# Google richsnippet videoobject does not appear as video

Tags: schema.org, google-rich-snippets, rich-snippets

On my video page I put videoobject metadata but google is not aware of that?

Am I missing something?

Here is my code:

```
<meta itemprop="name" content="Video namei" />
<meta itemprop="description" content="Video description" />
<meta itemprop="duration" content="PT05M13S" />
<meta itemprop="url" content="url at the browsers address bar"/>
<meta itemprop="thumbnailURL" content="image url from cdn" />
<span itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject" itemscope="" itemprop="thumbnail">
   <link href="same url with thumbnailURL" itemprop="contentUrl" />
   <meta content="640" itemprop="width" />
   <meta content="360" itemprop="height" />
</span>
<meta itemprop="embedURL" content="embed video link (swf)" />
<meta itemprop='playerType' content='Flash' />
<meta itemprop="uploadDate" content="2013-11-18T17:57:00+0200" />
<meta itemprop="width" content="640" />
<meta itemprop="height" content="360" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should nest all of your video markup within the video object schema, and you also should not hide the video title and description with a meta tag.  You need to use span tags for those instead.  And lastly, make sure your markup includes the contentURL item property, as Google will use it to generate video previews and helps them verify your video.

Comment: there is a video markup wraps all meta tags, I sould put it here, my bad. It says contentURL and embedURL are optional, only one of them required and I prefer embedURL. 
Actually some of the pages indexed lately comes with video thumbnail, but still not all of them, I think it is because google does not trust my domain anymore.
This thing happened after I changed my design and layout.